# Can I use case insensitive regex in Cypher query?

Tags: regex, cypher, memgraphdb

I am using Memgraph Platform 2.6.4 and I can't seem to use `(?i)` for case insensitive regular expression. It throws `"Invalid special open parenthesis"` error. What is the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memgraph does not support case insensitive flag (`(?i)`), but you can use `toLower` function to turn your strings into lowercase and compare them with another lowercase string. Here is the [documentation on regular expressions](https://memgraph.com/docs/cypher-manual/clauses/where#3-regular-expressions) and on [`toLower` function](https://memgraph.com/docs/cypher-manual/functions/#string-functions).